# Bloomberg API installation

Tags: python, bloomberg

I am trying to use the Bloomberg API on my university's screen, but I get the following error:

[image: error picture]

I know that it is difficult to ask for help remotely, even more so on a network were I dont have administrator permission. But I don't understand the error I am getting, if anyone can help me understand what this error means it would be a great help.

Comment: check out installation guide in first session of https://xbbg.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Install error for blpapi in python for bloomberg API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52897576/install-error-for-blpapi-in-python-for-bloomberg-api), it looks like you haven't properly installed the C++ SDK. I would recommend using `conda` for this so you don't have to worry about configuring you're environment appropriately, i.e.

```
conda install -c conda-forge blpapi
```

You can find other packaged versions of `blpapi` using `anaconda search blpapi`

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that the next time I meet with the IT personnel