# pdblp package is giving "No module named _internal"

Tags: python, api, bloomberg, pdblp

After importing `pdblp` package I'm getting an error that is described below. I have seen other questions about similar issues with `blpapi` issues but none of the solutions have worked.

I moved `blpapi_64.dll` and `.lib` into working directory from the Bloomberg API website C/C++ experimental download. Reinstalled using Conda python 3.7. twice. Could this be an admin rights issue?

```
import pdblp as blp


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-37a5527b622a>", line 1, in <module>
    import pdblp as blp

  File "C:\Users\abunker\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdblp\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pdblp import BCon  # NOQA

  File "C:\Users\abunker\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdblp\pdblp.py", line 4, in <module>
    import blpapi

  File "C:\Users\abunker\blpapi\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .internals import CorrelationId

  File "C:\Users\abunker\blpapi\internals.py", line 50, in <module>
    _internals = swig_import_helper()

  File "C:\Users\abunker\blpapi\internals.py", line 42, in swig_import_helper
    import _internals

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_internals'
```

Comment: solved - downgraded python version to from 3.7 to 3.6 and now working

Comment: more detail on solving this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52897576/install-error-for-blpapi-in-python-for-bloomberg-api/53860692#53860692