# ImportError _versionhelper when setting up Bloomberg Python API

Tags: python, bloomberg

I am trying to get set up with the Bloomberg Python API. I have been following along with this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@johann_78792/getting-started-with-bloombergs-python-desktop-api-5fd083b4193a). I am able to successfully `python -m pip install — index-url=https://bloomberg.bintray.com/pip/simple blpapi`, but then when I try to run `import blpapi` in the Python interpreter, I get the following error. How do I resolve this error (wondering if it has something to due with me using Python 3.8)?

```
ImportError:
---------------------------- ENVIRONMENT -----------------------------
Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
Architecture: ('32bit', 'WindowsPE')
Python: 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
Python implementation: CPython

blpapi 64-bit will be loaded from: "C:\blp\API\blpapi_cpp_3.13.1.1\lib\blpapi3_64.dll"
blpapi 32-bit will be loaded from: "C:\blp\API\blpapi_cpp_3.13.1.1\lib\blpapi3_32.dll"
System PATH: (* marks locations where blpapi was found)
    "C:\Windows\system32"
    "C:\Windows"
    "C:\Windows\System32\Wbem"
    "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\"
    "C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\"
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL"
    "C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL"
    "c:\nx_dll"
    "C:\Program Files\nodejs\"
  * "C:\blp\API\blpapi_cpp_3.13.1.1\lib"
    "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\"
    "C:\Users\cpage\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\"
    "C:\Users\cpage\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\"
    "C:\Users\cpage\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps"
  * "C:\blp\DAPI"
    "C:\blp\DAPI\DDE"
    "C:\Users\cpage\AppData\Roaming\npm"
    "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3"
    "C:\Users\cpage\AppData\Local\hyper\app-3.0.2\resources\bin"
    "C:\Users\cpage\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin"
  * "C:\blp\API\blpapi_cpp_3.13.1.1\lib"

blpapi package at: "C:\Users\cpage\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages"

Current directory: "C:\Users\cpage"

----------------------------------------------------------------------
No module named '_versionhelper'

Could not open the C++ SDK library.

Download and install the latest C++ SDK from:

    http://www.bloomberg.com/professional/api-library

If the C++ SDK is already installed, please ensure that the path to the library
was added to PATH before entering the interpreter.
```

Comment: There are several similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbloomberg%5D+%22Could+not+open+the+C%2B%2B+SDK+library%22 One of them mentions creating an environment variable: `BLPAPI_ROOT`.

Comment: Yes, I have already set `BLPAPI_ROOT` to be `C:\blp\API\blpapi_cpp_3.13.1.1\`.

Comment: Running through the same problem on Python 3.8 and blpapi_cpp_3.14.3.1

Comment: @gt6989b
    I'm also trying to use blpapi with Python 3.8. Tried by using pip to install it and by building from source (after setting BLPAPI_ROOT) from blpapi 3.14.3.1, blpapi 3.13.3.1, blpapi 3.12.3.1 and blpapi 3.12.2.1 but none of them seem to work. The error message is almost always the same (Import Error)

Comment: @raphaeldavidf perhaps better to downgrade to Python 3.7, everything works out of the box.

Comment: @gt6989b the new version works on 3.8, give it a try

Comment: @raphaeldavidf too late for us :) we were moving from 2.7 and ended up in 3.7 because of this and of some other problems. 3.8 is too recent I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You need to download the python blpapi package having the version matching your C++ lib.

In your case, since your C++ lib is 3.13.1.1, you can download the 3.13.1 python package:

`pip install --index-url=https://bloomberg.bintray.com/pip/simple blpapi==3.13.1`

Answer (score 2):

Just managed to make it run using version blpapi-3.15.2 using C++ API blpapi_cpp_3.15.0.1

To install run:

```
python -m pip install --index-url=https://bloomberg.bintray.com/pip/simple blpapi
```

to import use:

```
import os
with os.add_dll_directory('<...>\blpapi_cpp_3.15.0.1\lib'):
    import blpapi
```

or add `'<...>\blpapi_cpp_3.15.0.1\lib'` to PATH

Answer (score 1):

The following procedure works out of the box for CPython 2.7 and 3.7. A Bloomberg rep claims he verified it for CPython 3.5 as well:

1. Download the C++ BLP API from the [official Bloomberg repository](https://bloomberg.bintray.com/BLPAPI-Experimental-Generic/blpapi_cpp_3.14.3.1-windows.zip). If this link breaks, use [Bloomberg API Support homepage](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/) to find the up-to-date ones.
2. Unpack the archive to `C:\Programs\blpapi_cpp_3.14.3.1`
3. Exit from the shell.
4. Set the environment variable `BLPAPI_ROOT=C:\Programs\blpapi_cpp_3.14.3.1\`. Note that the trailing slash is important.
5. Start a new shell.
6. Execute `python -m pip install --index-url=https://bloomberg.bintray.com/pip/simple blpapi==3.14.0`
7. Check the installation by executing `python -c "import blpapi"`, which should pass without displaying messages.

Comment: I hit this problem about once a year and every time i have to search for solution. Since I had all proper versions already I just added the trailing slash from step 4 and copied **blpapi3_32.dll** and **blpapi3_64.dll**  to _C:\blp\DAPI_ folder. did not have to reinstall or download anything.  it might be that terminals .dll in DAPI folder got automatically updated to older one screwing things up.

Comment: @Vrun this makes sense, and would work, but is hacky to me. In addition, you run the risk that Bloomberg Terminal software will have a backward-incompatible released, cause the Terminal not to work.